# pthread_cond_wait sometimes will not receive the signal

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, pthreads, posix

I have a weird problem with `pthread_cond_wait` and `pthread_cond_signal`. I have arranged a series of threads. They are all in sleep state when started. A wake up function will signal these threads, do some work, and wait for the results.

In the setup below, `td` is thread data, containing the mutex and conditions, and `th` is an array containing the pointer to the threads:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) {
    pthread_cond_init(&td[i].cond, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&td[i].cond_mutex, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&td[i].work_mutex, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&td[i].cond_mutex);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&td[i].work_mutex);
    pthread_create(&th[i], NULL, thread_worker, (void *)&td[i]);
}
```

Thread worker is like this:

```
void*
thread_worker(void* data)
{
    THREAD_DATA *td = (THREAD_DATA *)data;
    while (1) {
        pthread_cond_wait(&td->cond, &td->cond_mutex);  // marker

        // do work ...

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&td->work_mutex);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

This `job` function is supposed to wake up all the threads, do the job, and wait for them to finish:

```
void
job()
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) {
        pthread_cond_signal(&td[i].cond);
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&td[i].work_mutex);  // block until the work is done
    }
}
```

In some rare situations (1 out of 1000 runs maybe), the above setup will encounter a freeze. When that happens, the 'marker' line in `thread_worker` will not be signaled by `pthread_cond_signal`, it just kept on waiting. It's very rare but it happens from time to time. I've produced numerous log messages, and I verified that `pthread_cond_wait` is always called before `pthread_cond_signal`. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: From your excerpt, `thread_worker` appears to _wait_ and _unlock_ a mutex that it didn't lock and thus doesn't own.  Not good.  Also, you appear to be using a condition variable without an associated predicate.  Change those two things, and see if you still have a problem.

Comment: @pilcrow, thanks but could you elaborate? The documentation of `pthread_cond_wait` clearly says that the mutex has to be locked before calling. What's an associated predicate? I understand I'm not checking the return variable, but it's not the problem I'm facing, I mean, it didn't return and kept on waiting.

Comment: It is an [error or worse to unlock a mutex that one didn't lock](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutex_lock.html#tag_16_439_03) and thus doesn't own, and by implication an error or worse to release a mutex during a _wait_ that one doesn't own.  As for predicates, it is as Blue Moon ([and others](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_cond_wait.html#tag_16_420_08_01)) say:  check your predicate after the _wait_ returns.

Comment: Well, the mutex is locked prior to conditional waiting (as illustrated in `td` initialization). I managed to dump the return variable to the log, `pthread_cond_wait` always returns zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing there that forces the `pthread_cond_wait()` to be called before the `pthread_cond_signal()`.  Despite what you say about logging, it's entirely possible for the logged lines to be out-of-sequence with what really happened.

You aren't using mutexes and condition variables correctly: mutexes should only be unlocked by the same thread that locked them, and condition variables should be paired with a test over some shared state (called a *predicate*).  The shared state is supposed to be protected by the mutex that is passed to `pthread_cond_wait()`.

For example, your example can be reworked to correctly use mutexes and condition variables.  First, add an `int work_status` to the `THREAD_DATA` structure, where `0` indicates that the thread is waiting for work, `1` indicates that work is available and `2` indicates that the work is complete.

You don't appear to need two mutexes in each `THREAD_DATA`, and you don't want to lock the mutex in the main thread when you're setting it up:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) {
    pthread_cond_init(&td[i].cond, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&td[i].cond_mutex, NULL);
    td[i].work_status = 0;
    pthread_create(&th[i], NULL, thread_worker, (void *)&td[i]);
}
```

Have the threads wait on `work_status` using the condition variable:

```
void*
thread_worker(void* data)
{
    THREAD_DATA *td = (THREAD_DATA *)data;

    while (1) {
        /* Wait for work to be available */
        pthread_mutex_lock(&td->cond_mutex);
        while (td->work_status != 1)
            pthread_cond_wait(&td->cond, &td->cond_mutex);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&td->cond_mutex);

        // do work ...

        /* Tell main thread that the work has finished */
        pthread_mutex_lock(&td->cond_mutex);
        td->work_status = 2;
        pthread_cond_signal(&td->cond);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&td->cond_mutex);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

...and set and wait on `work_status` as appropriate in `job()`:

```
void
job()
{
    /* Tell threads that work is available */
    for (size_t i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&td[i].cond_mutex);
        td[i].work_status = 1;
        pthread_cond_signal(&td[i].cond);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&td[i].cond_mutex);
    }

    /* Wait for threads to signal work complete */
    for (size_t i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&td[i].cond_mutex);
        while (td[i].work_status != 2)
            pthread_cond_wait(&td[i].cond, &td[i].cond_mutex);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&td[i].cond_mutex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I did realize it's possible the log is out of order but I didn't figure out how to keep them in sequence.

Comment: Hello again, I noticed you used a blocking while loop to watch for `work_status` variable change. Is this mandatory? Won't this maxout CPU when no job is available?

Comment: @HeShiming: No, because the body of the `while()` loop is a call to `pthread_cond_wait()`, which will suspend the thread.

Answer (score 2):

Some check lists:

1) Do you lock the mutex `td->cond_mutex` before waiting on the cond variable? Otherwise, it's undefined.

2) Do you check predicate *after* pthread_cond_wait() returns? Typical usage is

```
while(!flag) pthread_cond_wait(&cv, &mutex); //waits on flag
```

which is not what you have. This is to protect against spurious wake-ups and also ensure the predicate hasn't changed in the meantime.

3) `pthread_cond_signal()` is guaranteed to wake up at least one thread. You may want to use `pthread_cond_broadcast()` if there are multiple threads waiting on the same condition variable.

4) If no thread is waiting on a conditional variable then `pthread_cond_signal()` or `pthread_cond_broadcast()` has no effect.

Comment: Thanks but I believe I got all those points correctly. 1), if you check my initialization code of `td`, the mutex is locked. 2), I can't do `while(flag)` and condition waiting at the same time. They are separate problems aren't they? My current situation is that the waiting won't return. 3), I've got separate `cond` and `mutex` for each thread. 4), the thread is waiting on `cond` as `thread_worker` illustrated.